# how do we check whether a particular modal window opens or not using teststack.white Automation framework?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

I am having an issue relating to modal window.

Inside the application that i am automating, a modal window opens if the user has some data but if it has not then it will not open. how can we put an "if statement" e.g, if modal window exist then do some work else skip. because i am having an error at this statement

```
Window childWindow = mainWindow.ModalWindow("child");
```

it is throwing an exception because it could not search for window with name "child". and i know that it does not exist. it should skip it if it does not exist.

Comment: can you not check the properties or values that the Modal window uses and then if all conditions are met ..then open or you can open the modal window and upon Save or close check values if nothing were there skip else do some process

Comment: i think you did not understand my question fully. let me rephrase it:

Comment: How do I check if a modal window with some name say "ModalDialog" exists if I have the instance of the base window in "_currentWindow"?
If I try :

_currentWindow.ModalWindow(searchCriteria);

This throws a Null Reference Exception if the modal window does not exist.
Do we have a way to check whether the modal window with given search criteria exists or not before we execute the above statement?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to se if there are any modal windows before executiong the ModalWindow Method

```
Window childWindow = null;
if(mainWindow.ModalWindows().Any())
{
    childWindow = mainWindow.ModalWindow("child");
}
```

else you can try to define criteria, or while for a certain timeout

```
...
var timer = new StopWatch();
timer.Start();
Window childWindow = null;
do 
{
    childWindow = mainWindow.ModalWindow("child");
} while (childWindow != null || timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeOutInMs);
...
```

Hope it helps.

Rik

Answer (score 0):

My working code (AutomationUI):

```
using System.Windows.Automation;

Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            mainWindow.AutomationElement,
            TreeScope.Descendants,
            (sender, e) =>
            {
                var element = sender as AutomationElement;
                if (!(element.Current.LocalizedControlType == "Dialog" && element.Current.Name == "modalWindowTitle"))
                    return;

                Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
                // Here run your code. The modal window was opened
            });
```